# Add tag for Dwarf/Dwarves?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a tag for elf/elves but not for dwarf/dwarves.

Should one be added?

Comment: On the main, or on meta?

Comment: On the main tag list

Comment: I've removed the [status-declined] tag from this, because tags in general aren't something the mods decide, and obviously the tag eventually ended up being made anyway. (I've also changed the main tag from [feature-request] to [discussion], since there's no feature being requested.)

Comment: We covered this again a couple of years later and came to a different conclusion. I've closed this as a duplicate of that more recent discussion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### There's an [elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elf) tag? Why?

Looking at the [elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elf) and [half-elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-elf) questions (there are only five between them, all of them from 2011), some of them seem like the tag is unneeded and some it's arguably appropriate. I imagine that if they'd been made today, the tags would have been removed; the site's policies have evolved since then.

### Are there questions that need a [dwarf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf) tag?

Just because there's a tag for one thing doesn't mean we need tags for all complementary things as well. Tags don't get made in a vacuum; they're created because there is a need in the community. If you ask a question that you feel needs to be tagged this way after reading up on [what tags are for](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/tagging), that's when the tag should be made. Anything before that is jumping the gun and adding unnecessary "noise" to the site.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think we need the [elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elf) tag, so I don't think we need a `dwarf` tag, as much as I like the stout bearded folk.

The [elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elf) tag is only used on two questions, both related to 4e racial abilities, but I don't know what it would help people find.  I suggest we consider removing it.

Comment: Fair point.  This isn't 4e.stackexchange, but rpg.stackexchange.  On that point, there probably shouldn't be class specific tags either.

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo Come on into [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat) for that discussion, if you like.

Comment: There is an argument for tags like [dnd-4e-elf] or [dnd-4e-cleric], because those can be useful to search on for people looking for build advice/issues. I know such subtags have been frowned on in the past, but if we remove class tags, tags like this may be a sensible replacement.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not.

The point of the SE tagging system is to be emergent - to appear as needed to usefully describe and group questions. Therefore we don't create them 'on spec' - they should appear because there's already a set of questions they'd help out.

Furthermore, tags like "elves" and dwarves" are bad from several points of view.  There's very little value to clustering a question about Shadowrun elves and D&D elves - besides some nominal similarity, they're different things. So mainly you're using the tag to cluster within games/game groups. The only two "elf" questions are within D&D 4e, but that then makes "elf" a somewhat undesirable meta tag (doesn't stand alone as the only tag on a question). [We try not to do meta tags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) except in very limited circumstances.

The real question is - why do you think there should be?  "Parity" with the elf tag is not really a good reason in and of itself.

Comment: "The real question is - why do you think there should be? "Parity" with the elf tag is not really a good reason in and of itself. " -->   I didn't say their should be.  I said, "Should there be?"

Comment: @TheEvilGreebo It's implicit in making a meta post and getting everyone's attention that you think there's a discrepancy that might need correcting. If not... well, what's the problem?

Comment: I'm afraid that you're confusing inference and implication.

Comment: <Rolls eyes> if you're just asking out of boredom, we probably have better things to do then.