# Star Wars: Edge of the Empire (and subsequent) tags

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

*Star Wars: Edge of the Empire* will soon be joined by *Star Wars: Age of Rebellion*, and some time thereafter a third book with an unknown title. The format will almost certainly be the same, though: *Star Wars: X*.

Fantasy Flight Games will be rolling out these games using an approach similar to the one they've used with Warhammer 40k, wherein the same core mechanics are used, and each book stands alone but also adds more skills, settings, equipment, and so on to the previous books.

The tag used for all Warhammer: 40k books is *wh40k*.

*Star Wars* is the tag used for discussions of roleplaying in the Star Wars universe, regardless of specific game system.

Given all of the above, what are your thoughts as to what tag or tags would be appropriate for the FFG Star Wars games?

Answer (score 4):

### Your suggestion makes sense

...and should be revisited if and when the need arises.

> *The point of the SE tagging system is to be emergent - to appear as needed to usefully describe and group questions. Therefore we don't create them 'on spec' - they should appear because there's already a set of questions they'd help out.* [@mxyzplk](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/140/mxyzplk), in [this answer](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3069/4398) to another proposed-tag question.

We don't yet seem to have a set of questions about these things out of which a tagging system can organically grow. Forcing the growth of an SE construct out of the idea of what "ought to" or "will" be, rather than meeting the reality of the site as it is discovered, is something we try to avoid (much to my chagrin, at times; I like heading things off at the pass, too).

Comment: I suspected that might be the case, but couldn't find mention of it anywhere. Thanks!