# Should there be a 'Parent tag' for the FFG Star Wars games?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-systems

We currently have [age-of-rebellion](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/age-of-rebellion), [force-and-destiny](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/force-and-destiny), and [edge-of-the-empire](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-of-the-empire) tags for Star Wars.  These three games use very much the same system - they use the same quirky dice, the same skill and ability check system, the same advancement track system, etc.  They also share the same exact subset of the Star Wars universe.  And while I will acknowledge they are not identical systems, there is far more alike between them than there are differences.  More to the point, examining the questions already tagged with one or more of the game tags, the vast majority of the questions apply to all games.  A large proportion of them already carry the tags of multiple versions of the game.

They are far more alike in system and setting than [vampire-the-masquerade](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vampire-the-masquerade) and [werewolf-the-apocalypse](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/werewolf-the-apocalypse) and those are covered by the [old-world-of-darkness](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/old-world-of-darkness) 'parent tag'.

I am not suggesting going out and editing all [32 current questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/edge-of-the-empire+or+age-of-rebellion+or+force-and-destiny) (for now), but I am asking is if I were to ask a question applicable to one or more of those games, should I create such an umbrella tag?

This was [previously discussed](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3091/star-wars-edge-of-the-empire-and-subsequent-tags?rq=1), with the conclusion that we should discuss this further when the new games come out.  Two years later, those games have come out.  As noted here, we have a [wh40k](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wh40k) to cover the exact same situation that Fantasy Flight has put us in for that universe.

Comment: Note that the [wh40k] tag isn't really parallel to what's being proposed here. It covers both the setting and acts as an umbrella for the game lines, including lines not produced by FFG, making it an unusual tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the reason such a tag doesn't yet exist is: what would it be *called*? There's no obvious umbrella term for these games. In theory we could have [star-wars-ffg](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-ffg) or [ffg-star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffg-star-wars), but the discoverability of those is low because it doesn't have much currency as *the* name for this set of games. Unlike WoD, there isn't a widely-used and -recognised parent term, partly because FFG has deliberately made the games difficult to refer to them collectively.

A tag for this set of games might be theoretically useful, and would even make sense from a searching standpoint to find Q&A relevant to all three games, but that theoretical utility is mooted by being not very useful in practice because there's no term that people would intuitively be searching for or trying to tag with.

What appears to happen in practice is that people tag with the game they are playing, or if they are well-informed enough to know it applies to them all, tagging with all three of them.

So yes, these could have a parent tag. But they shouldn't have one unless there is a natural name for the set of games already that would be obvious to new and casual users of RPG.se. The fact that there isn't one yet strongly indicates that such a natural name doesn't exist, since *someone* would have used it by now if there was one. The current tagging has some flaws, but a parent tag that's a neologism wouldn't be used naturally there therefore wouldn't fix those flaws.

Comment: I think it's telling that even the publisher doesn't have a banner term/forum/etc.

Comment: It should be noted, that the greater internet community refer to the three games either as all EOTE or 'FFG Star Wars'

Answer (score -3):

Tagging is an "emergent folksonomy." This means tags appear when they are needed.  If no one has asked a question meaningful across the games, then there's no need for the parent tag.  Once they do, then we should discuss if the tag is named right or whatnot.  Proactively creating tags, however, is bad for a variety of reasons and we should avoid it.

Comment: See edit.  We have reached this point.

Comment: I don't know - as they are indeed different games, how do you see this working? The poster is probably best qualified to tag with multiple of the games that do fit. Even on the FFG site there's not a rollup forum, they're all different - https://community.fantasyflightgames.com/forum/11-roleplaying-games/

Comment: For one, a very large number of questions (proportionally) already have more than one system tag.  for another, some system basics questions predate the release of AoR or FaD, and wouldn't have been tagged between them.  Additionally, the few places the games diverge are documented.  It is a non-subjective process to tell where one question is actually specific to a game and to where it is applicable to all games.  For now, combining the very common case of two tags, or all three, to one tag would be a start

Answer (score -3):

Since this question was answered the situation surrounding Fantasy Flight Games has changed.  The game was moved to Asmodee's RPG division, Edge.
Around this time, FFG/Edge/Asmodee released a series of books under the "Star Wars Roleplaying" brand.

https://www.edge-studio.net/categories-games/star-wars-roleplaying/

These books do not fit into the old categories like Edge of Empire, etc. but are fully compatible with all three previous systems, and serve as a system unifying set of books.

So perhaps the tag, should there be one, might be called Star Wars Roleplaying System?

Comment: SWRP would be a tag that does not match neatly: there have been about 5 or 6 Star Wars RPGs.

Comment: Two things: 1st: Edge and FFG are both subsidiaries of Asmodee. The FFG license was shifted to Edge in 2021 as far as I can figure out. No word that the license expired in 2023, but in 2022, they had a new print run of material. 2nd: Where do you substantiate that they **lost their license** from?

Comment: On the first point, I knew this, but I was unclear about this in my post.  
On the second point, I biffed it.  In both cases, I edited the post to more closely confirm to what is verifiable. Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: The claim that the system is "likely discontinued" seems unsubstantiated still.

Comment: Fair enuf - I will just take it out - it's not really relevant anyway.