# Should we throw [star-wars] out the airlock?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, game-systems, burninate-request

Anecdotally, I've seen a couple times that it's very easy to tag something with [star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) thinking it's a substitute for the nonexistent [ffg-star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ffg-star-wars) (see [Should there be a 'Parent tag' for the FFG Star Wars games?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/should-there-be-a-parent-tag-for-the-ffg-star-wars-games)) or other specific game tags, so it seems like there's at least one con to leaving it around.

**So what are the pros?**

Several questions are using it specifically to talk about the setting... but they're either world-building or game-rec questions that have been closed. I was figuring there would be questions asking about how to handle certain Star Wars-y things in an RPG context that are setting-specific but system-agnostic, but there seem to be fewer than I expected:

- [Droid hacking in Star Wars?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/droid-hacking-in-star-wars) The part of this question that's not better answered by scifi.se seems pretty low quality to me.
- [How to play a character that has an alien mindset and thought process?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15571/how-to-play-a-character-that-has-an-alien-mindset-and-thought-process) This is solid - the question and answer are both more specific to Star Wars than the title would suggest.
- [How many people does it take to steal a Star Destroyer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-many-people-does-it-take-to-steal-a-star-destroyer) is a good question with an amazing answer, but better suited to sff.se - there's really nothing RPG-specific there.
- [Who took the Star Wars RPG license over from WotC in 2011?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6026/who-took-the-star-wars-rpg-license-over-from-wotc-in-2011) is a fair question, but not likely to be what someone is searching for in the tag.
- The best use of this tag I can think of would be a question like [How to embed a Force user (w/ metaphysical powers) into a technical party?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/88231/how-to-embed-a-force-user-w-metaphysical-powers-into-a-technical-party/88239), but that one's been closed.

Just about all the rest are rules questions so specific to particular game systems that it's tough to see how they would be useful outside the systems in question, which they're already tagged with (or should be).

What do people think?

Comment: Are Star Wars d6 and FFG Star Wars the only Star Wars RPGs, or are there more?

Comment: @ThomasJacobs There are three official ones: WEG's, WotC's, and FFG's. There may (likely will) be more in the future, because that's what happens with big-name/big-cost licenses.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Of course, Star Wars D20. Forgot about that one.

Comment: @ThomasJacobs There are actually somewhere between four and six: [tag: star-wars-d6] (Star Wars D6, WEG), [tag:star-wars-d20] (Star Wars D20, WotC), [tag:star-wars-saga-edition] (Star Wars: Saga Edition, WotC), [tag:edge-of-the-empire] (Star Wars: Edge of the Empire, FFG), [tag:star-wars-aor]/[tag:age-of-rebellion] (Star Wars: Age of Rebellion, FFG), [tag:force-and-destiny] (Star Wars: Force and Destiny, FFG). I'm unsure how "different" the three FFG games are, but Star Wars D20 and Star Wars Saga are definitely distinct (scale difference similar to 3e and 5e D&D).

Comment: @AceCalhoon Good point. From what I know the differences in tone are similar to those of FFG's 40k games, but more subtle.

Comment: The Edge of the Empire, Age of Rebellion and Force and Destiny are pretty much the same game with different aims for the group: People like Han (rogues), Rebels and lost Jedi

Answer (score 14):

No, we don't need to jettison that tag. It's a setting and a topic people ask about; there's no reason to get rid of it. I could very reasonably go ask a [fate-accelerated](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fate-accelerated) [star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) [stunts](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stunts) question tomorrow about emulating jedi mind tricks in a Fate stunt in a custom Star Wars game. It does need some housekeeping though.

You've brought up the topicality of a few questions, so I'll go through those too.

- [Droid hacking in Star Wars?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/droid-hacking-in-star-wars): I've voted to close this [as too broad](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/26844/droid-hacking-in-star-wars#comment202655_26844). (And it's closed now.)
- [How to play a character that has an alien mindset and thought process?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15571/how-to-play-a-character-that-has-an-alien-mindset-and-thought-process): Totally solid. I agree with you.
- [How many people does it take to steal a Star Destroyer?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/7960/how-many-people-does-it-take-to-steal-a-star-destroyer) is notably asked within the framework of one *West End Game's Star Wars RPG*, which we should have a tag for (and apparently don't). By our [campaign research rules](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1609/1204) this whole question's fine: the question's inherently tied up with a bunch of players in an RPG, and the accepted answer goes into game advice *as well as* actual fictional universe lore insofar as its author needs to. That author is Brian Ballsun-Stanton, and he has not been one to shy away from essay-length answers [when given the chance](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51275/1204).
- [Who took the Star Wars RPG license over from WotC in 2011?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6026/who-took-the-star-wars-rpg-license-over-from-wotc-in-2011): Fair on topic question. It's also about Star Wars. But it could probably do with a game-specific tag. (Boy, am I counting *three* different Star Wars TTRPG publishers now..? West End, Fantasy Flight, and WotC?)

Summary:

- We're missing some tags for specific Star Wars games, maybe.
- Star Wars as a tag has nothing wrong with it, can be used healthily, and we might as well leave the Star Wars stuff tagged as such.

I'd say we let it die of natural causes (tag cleanup mechanisms) if we wind up without any questions tagged [star-wars](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) at some point, but it doesn't seem likely that'll happen, given we have a few of those.

Comment: [star-wars-d6] is the weg game tag.

Comment: I've tagged the last question with both the "source" and "destination" licenses. Not sure if that's right or not but it seems to me to be a question about both, even if the asker didn't know it at the time.

Comment: @SirTechSpec Generally not; we don't tag questions based on what their answers turn out to be.

Comment: @d7 got it, thanks!